# How to get string from a parse in java instead of getting id?

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, parse-platform, developer-tools

I am making an android app and currently stuck on signup page.
Trying to enter values in database using parse and storing the database on parse.com
 The values are entered in `EditText` box and are having some id say `"name"`
 On using that for database, my java file includes command like

```
 parseObject text=new parseObject("Signup");

 text.put("Key_id_name", R.id.name);
```

//Due to this, id of EditText box is coming in database.

Kindly help me how to get the value entered in that.

Answer (score 0):

Use [getText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText%28%29) method of `EditText` class as below.

```
EditText field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
String fieldValue = field.getText().toString();
```

Then add it to your map

```
text.put("Key_id_name", fieldValue);
```

*R.id.name* will simply give you the generated Id and not the value.

Comment: I am using EditText.. still if I am making object of that and doing like this way, it isnt working

Comment: @user2929318 Updated the reply to use EditText class. Please check the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
parseObject text=new parseObject("Signup");
text.put("Key_id_name", view.getText().toString());
```

Comment: I am using EditText.. still if I am making object of that and doing like this way, it isnt working

Comment: @user2929318 what do you mean by _"it isnt working"_? Also please post your whole code. Maybe you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your view has a TextView with the id R.id.name?

In that case you should use findViewById(R.id.name) in your activity code

See these docs:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText()

Something like this:

```
TextView idText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
String idString = idText.getText().toString();
text.put("Key_id_name", idString);
```

Good luck =)

Comment: I am using EditText.. still if I am making object of that and doing like this way, it isnt working